# POST a file with curl command

Tags: html, curl

I want to post a file with this command:

```
curl -L -k -u myusername:mypassword -X POST HOSTaddress -F file.xml=@./myfile.xml
```

However, I get error (need POST Contents). I am sure that myfile.xml is in my current directory. So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your @file parameter with quotes and also make sure that the name of this parameter is correct `file.xml` it probably might be just `file`.

So it should look something like shown below:

```
curl -L -k -u myusername:mypassword -X POST HOSTaddress -F 'file=@./myfile.xml'
```

Comment: is the path correct? can you try changing ./ to just /

Comment: Well, I did not know what I did but it is working now :). Thanks!